# Updating Phonegap Cordova - Black status bar on bottom of App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After i updated the Cordova and Phonegap i have white bar at the bottom of the app.What i have noticed is that when i rotate the Phone and put it back to the vertical positon the white bar dispear.

Earlier my code was

```
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />
```

now that I have changed to :

```
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

Please can anybody help in this issue.

Comment: Updating a plugin don't cause UI / behavior changes. Problem could be in you HTML/CSS.

Comment: The problem despear when i rotate my phone.I think there is problem with  this plugin.